# How do I create a drawable that expand only vertically / horizontally with XML in Android

Tags: android, android-resources, android-drawable, nine-patch, android-shape

I want to know if there is a way to obtain the effect of an image expanding with solid color only from one side.

Suppose you start with a bitmap like this:
[image: drawable-xxxhdpi/my_bitmap]

and you want to setup an XML drawable so that it expand and shrink horizontally keeping its features but vertically I want it to add solid "blue" color on the top without touching the image so that if I place as background of a widget that is less wide and higher I obtain this:

[image: drawable/my_expandable_bitmap]

If 9patches provided the ability to just make a single side expand this would be perfect. But 9patches force you to define an expandable region on both directions: this would destroy the shape I have in the bottom.

This is what I can achieve with a 9patch:
[image: 9patch horizontal expansion]

This is what i want (keep in mind I want it to expand as much as needed vertically without scaling the arrow (the arrow should always have the same height):
[image: wanted result]

I can obtain this playing around with layout but it's not good for performance.

Finally I can write my custom Drawable, and I know how to do it, but it wouldn't work on a RemoteView and, when not working with Remote View, it's ugly having to set it by code.

Anyone know of a way of producing this effect with XML drawable only?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a 9patch if i'm not mistaken.
Just select a small part of the image on the left side to expand vertically.
Then the bottom part of your image shouldn't be stretched and it wil look like it's adding solid color on the top.

**EDIT**

This is what I can get with a 9patch, it gets flattened out, but it's not adding a straight line like your example.

**Original**

[image]

**wider** (doesn't really show well here, but it is wider)

[image]

Comment: no you can't, a 9patch force you to define a rectangular area for expansion. I means you also have to give it a least 1 pixel for expansion horizontally, which will destroy the image features

Comment: So you don't want it to change horizontally at all? Because in your answer you say that you want it to shrink and expand horizontally as well. Shouldn't yiu get this effect if you select the complete width as stretch zone in a 9patch? If your image stretches without being defined as a 9patch, your arch gets 'flattened' aswell, no?

Comment: I want it to stretch horizontally by scaling. Which is different then stretching by expanding. if you download my photo and try to make a 9patch out of it you'll immediately understand what I'm talking about. It's harder to explain with words than to actually visualize it (or it's just that english is not my main language and I don't know how to better explain it

Comment: I've added 2 images to show why a 9patch does not do what I want

Comment: i added 2 images aswell, since my result is different than yours